# can't adjust the number of items in the matrix

Tags: r

I want to fill the matrix w according to the code given below

```
num_feats = 4726 
num_obsvs = 500
mod_size = 35
num_causl = 35

W<-matrix(0,num_feats,num_feats)

for(i in 2:(as.integer(num_feats/mod_size)-1))

 w[(i-1)*mod_size:(i)*mod_size,(i-1)*mod_size:(i)*mod_size]<-matrix(1,ncol= mod_size,nrow = mod_size)

if (i!=as.integer(num_feats/mod_size-1))
{
 w[(i+1)*mod_size-1,(i+1)*mod_size]<-1
 w[(i+1)*mod_size,(i+1)*mod_size-1]<-1
}
```

But It gives me this error :

> Error in w[(i - 1) * mod_size:(i) * mod_size, (i - 1) * mod_size:(i) *
>   :    number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement
>   length

I tried to adjust the size but now way! how can i resolve it please ?

Comment: `mod_size <- 35;
i <- 2;
length((i-1)*mod_size:(i)*mod_size) == mod_size` returns
`#FALSE` So the error is telling you the part of `w` you're trying to replace is a different size than the replacement you're providing. You would get the same error if you tried, for example, `x <- 1:10; x[1:2] <- 40:50`

Comment: @Ryan, how should I do to adjust parameters to get correct affectation.